# Is it possible to start a thread in Java from the object in its argument?

Tags: java, multithreading

is it possible to do something like this in Java? I'm just wondering.

First, I just create a new thread that has one argument.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Person());
```

Then, in the constructor of Person() I would like to start that thread.
So is something like this possible?

```
public Person() {
    // Here belongs some code for the constructor and then
    // I would like to start the thread
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Can you explain the use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. Before Java can call `Thread()` constructor it first has to eagerly evaluate all arguments, including call to `Person()` constructor. This means that by the time `Person` constructor is called, the outer `Thread` object doesn't even exist or was not yet initialized so you cannot really use it.

Comment: One speculation, which object will be created first - Thread or Person?

Comment: @RohitJain: I am not sure which object is *created* (in terms of memory allocation) first, and it doesn't really matter. But you can easily see that `Person`'s constructor must be called first.

Comment: @Tomasz.. Yeah that is pretty clear. But I only asked it on reading your 3rd line. May be if `Thread` object is created first using first `new` operator, then that last part is not completely correct.

Comment: @RohitJain: thanks, I clarified a bit. Does it look better now?

Comment: @Tomasz.. Yeah, now it looks fine. :)

Answer (score 1):

No.

You do not have the reference to the thread inside `Person` constructor. So, the thread still does not exist.

Even if you had it, doing something like

```
 public Person() {
   Thread a = new MyThread(this);
 }
```

is bad practice, because you are passing an instance (`this`) that might not have been fully initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? Note the use of `{start()}` which avoids all of the issues with calling `start` in the constructor.

```
  new Thread() {
    { start(); }
    public void run() {
     ...
    }
  };
```

You can see the original [here](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue149.html).